# Not able to download picture from facebook iframe

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have developed a simple facebook application in which i'm merging facebook user's name with an image. Output of this code is correct but when I try to download this file, some invalid image gets downloaded( show invalid image when opened).

Here is my code for image.php file

```
<?php 
header("Content-Type: image/png"); 
include_once 'facebook.php';
include_once 'config.php';
include_once 'token.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
'secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY,
));

$me = $facebook->api('/me');
$im = ImageCreateFrompng("image.png"); 
$black = ImageColorAllocate($im, 0, 0, 0); 
$start_x = 35; 
$start_y = 230; 
Imagettftext($im, 20, 0, $start_x, $start_y, $black, 'ambient.ttf', $me['name']); 
Imagejpeg($im, '', 100); 
ImageDestroy($im); 

//code to download this image
$imgDestinationPath = 'download.png';
$url = 'apps.facebook.com/myapp/image.php';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
file_put_contents($imgDestinationPath, $content);

?>
```

now here is the confusing part. when i put a static text in place of $me['name'] and change $url to 'mysite.com/image.php intead of apps.facebook.com/myapp/image.php then the image gets downloaded. I also tried changing $url to mysite.com/image.php with dynamic text, but the problem is same

Comment: I think you should change the url to <yourdomain>/image.php

Comment: i tried it. problem is still the same

Comment: did you try changing the destination path as well?

Comment: did you check if you are getting value in $me['name'] ? try to print it first.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with the call to the *api* method of the facebook class, that probably won't be called when the script is called through the *file_get_contents*.

Try putting the name as a GET variable in the url of file_get_contents, in this way it will be kinda cheating since you will have a dynamically static variable